# Using the `kubectl explain` command

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: nginx
    securityContext: 
      capabilities: 
        add: ["NET_ADMIN", "SYS_TIME"]
```

To better understand the subject and the fields in yaml i wanted to see what fields can i add to "capabilities" by using : `Kubectl explain pod.spec.securityContext.capabilities`

i got nothing. "capabilities field does not exist" .

1. 1.how far does the explain command go ?
2. 2.how can i find the fields i can add to let's say capabilities ?
3. 3.if for example i search for kubectl explain pod.spec.volumes and i get :

   RESOURCE: volumes <[]Object>

   the  "[]" tells me that the next field will be a list and i will be
   adding '-' ?

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Avoid asking multiple questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the kubectl command covers all fields. The reason you got the error is that capabilities is on the [containers security context spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#securitycontext-v1-core) not the [pod security context spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#podsecuritycontext-v1-core) 
The correct explain command is therefore

`kubectl explain pod.spec.containers.securityContext.capabilities`

You can browse through API Reference instead of using explain if you are in doubt of the existing fields or use explain one step at a time. i.e. `kubectl explain pod.spec.securityContext` first to see available fields.

To answer question 3, yes [] implies an array and '-' is a way in to specify an array in yaml.

Comment: Got it, finally i am starting to understand the structure, thank you !